# Is there a blocking redis library for node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, npm

Redis is very fast. For most part on my machine it is as fast as say native Javascript statements or function calls in node.js. It is easy/painless to write regular Javascript code in node.js because no callbacks are needed. I don't see why it should not be that easy to get/set key/value data in Redis using node.js.

Assuming node.js and Redis are on the same machine, are there any npm libraries out there that allow interacting with Redis on node.js using blocking calls? I know this has to be a C/C++ library interfacing with V8.

Comment: You do not want blocking libraries in node.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do blocking calls on nodejs in a compelling and useful way?

Comment: I understand blocking calls can create massive bottlenecks. I can use native Javascript functions (ex: regular expressions etc.) and loops in a blocking way that execute very quickly in V8. If getting/setting Redis data can be almost as fast, why can I not use some blocking Redis library that has functions such as getSync, hsetSync etc.? This makes writing code far more easier (val = client.getSync(key); #1 line) instead of using callbacks (3+ lines).

Comment: your over estimating "almost". redis is at least 1000 times as slow as for loops and regex.

Comment: Why did you choose to use node.js if you want to work with blocking calls?

Comment: You, clearly, have not actually profiled any of this. You will not be scalable if your redis library were blocking, and if you are not worried about scaling I don't know why you care about this performance detail in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose you want to ensure all your redis insert operations have been performed. To achieve that, you can use the MULTI commands to insert keys or perform other operations. 
The https://github.com/mranney/node_redis module queues up the commands pushed in multi object, and executes them accordingly.

That way you only require one callback, at the end of exec call.

Comment: Good tradeoff! A single callback, a single multi block that runs multiple commands, together helps me avoid the long callback spagetti.

Comment: Good it works for you :). I had the same problem, and that is how i overcame it :D. Not to mention the performance gain, and no bottlenecks again.

Comment: No, you don't want MULTI, you just want pipelining, which solves this problem.

Comment: And use `Q` to avoid the long callback spaghetti.  https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: I would just like to note that nodejs may be used as the platform of a single user desktop application.  It does not have to be for a server.

Answer (score 10):

This seems like a common bear-trap for developers who are trying to get used to Node's evented programming model.

What happens is this: you run into a situation where the async/callback pattern isn't a good fit, you figure what you need is some way of doing blocking code, you ask Google/StackExchange about blocking in Node, and all you get is admonishment on how bad blocking is.

They're right - blocking, ("wait for the result of this before doing anything else"), isn't something you should try to do in Node. But what I think is more helpful is to realize that 99.9% of the time, you're not really looking for a way to do blocking, you're just looking for a way to make your app, "wait for the result of this before going on to do that," which is not exactly the same thing.

Try looking into the idea of "flow control" in Node rather than "blocking" for some design patterns that could be a clearer fit for what you're trying to do. Here's a list of libraries to check out:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-async-flow

I'm new to Node too, but I'm really digging Async: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: +1 for pointing out a good, usable tool. i want to add that `yield` / generators are just around the corner (already in unstable 0.11.x); on https://github.com/loveencounterflow/coffy-script i try to show how useful it is to alleviate some asynchronous worries.

Comment: You can hack the open source google v8 engine and maybe add multithreading and condition variables.

Answer (score 7):

Blocking code creates a *MASSIVE* bottleneck.

If you use blocking code your server will become *INCREDIBLY* slow.

Remember, node is single threaded. So any blocking code, will block node *for every* connected client.

Your own benchmarking shows it's fast enough for *one* client. Have you benchmarked it with a 1000 clients? If you try this you will see why blocking code is *bad*

Comment: which would obviously negate the benefits of node.js. +1

Comment: I do not believe accessing Redis running on the same server as node.js synchronously, creates massive bottleneck. Most of my get/set operations on Redis key/val DB are lightning fast.

Comment: @pm8 they are lightning fast for one client. But what if your doing it for 1000 at the same time ? Massive bottleneck.

Comment: Trust the event stack. If 1000 clients blocked for even 10 milliseconds each, that would be 10 seconds before your last response goes out. In these 10 seconds, other clients will wait, and your site will be unresponsive. Epic server slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Redis is quick it is not instantaneous ... this is why you *must* use a callback if you want to continue execution ensuring your values are there.

The only way I think you *could* (and am not suggesting you do) achieve this use a callback with a variable that is the predicate for leaving a timer.